# Symfony3 - File constraint validation on collectionType

Tags: symfony

I have a form with 4 unmapped fields. Each fields can have [0,n] file.

Here is my FormType (works well):

```
$builder            
        ->add('identityProofs', CollectionType::class, array(
           'entry_type' => FileType::class, 'allow_add' => true, 'prototype' => true, 'label' => false))
       ->add('articlesOfAssociations', CollectionType::class, array(              
           'entry_type' => FileType::class, 'allow_add' => true, 'prototype' => true, 'label' => false))
       ->add('registrationProofs', CollectionType::class, array(
           'entry_type' => FileType::class, 'allow_add' => true, 'prototype' => true, 'label' => false))
       ->add('shareolderDeclarations', CollectionType::class, array(
           'entry_type' => FileType::class, 'allow_add' => true, 'prototype' => true, 'label' => false))           
    ;
```

For each File, I need to add constraints like maxSize. I can't find any doc about it without using annotation (which I can't use because I don't have mapped class). Do I need to add a class, or can I do something like that (already tried, it doesn't work):

```
->add('articlesOfAssociations', CollectionType::class, array(
           'constraints'  => array(
               new Collection(
                   ['fields' => ['File' => new File(['maxSize' => '10k'])]])),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass constraint to interior form type (file), not the parent (collection) one.

To do that you should use [`entry_options`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options) option of collection type. Value of this option is passed into every instance of entry form type (`FileType` in your case). So it could be something like:

```
->add('articlesOfAssociations', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_options' => array(
           'constraints'  => array(
               new File(['maxSize' => '10k']),
           ),
        ),
```